# Clearing jQuery timeout outside of scope

Tags: jquery, settimeout, cleartimeout

I have a clock that triggers a 'tic' every 2400ms.
On 'tic', I want the children of my parent divs to toggleClass, but not all at the same time: I use their parent's index to offset the trigger in time, so that it happens in some sort of wave.
On top of that, or maybe should I have started with it, I want none of this to happen while the user is scrolling.
I managed to get my container to stop listening to 'tic' with a .off() but I cannot seem to **clear the timeout that is responsible for the offset**.

Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/andinse/w878ft4z/7/

I am new to jQuery and a little bit lost in the nesting of this all.

Any help greatly appreciated!

```
var $parents = $('.parents');
var $parent = $('.parent');
var $child = $('.child');

var $speed = 2400;
var $loopLength = 5;

setInterval(function clock() {
  $parents.trigger('tic');
}, $speed);

$.fn.play = function() {
  $(this).on('tic', function() {
    $child.each(function() {
      var $that = $(this);
      var $offset = ($that.parent().index() % $loopLength) * $speed / $loopLength;
      setTimeout(function() {
        $that.toggleClass('special');
      }, $offset);
    });
    return this;
  });
};

$parents.play();

$(document).scroll(function() {
  $parents.off('tic');
  clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
  $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
    $parents.play();
  }, 200));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a version of your snippet that defines private arrays outside of your nests and then assigns unique timeOuts to array positions, before clearing and reestablishing in sequence:

```js
var $parents = $('.parents');
var $parent = $('.parent');
var $child = $('.child');

var $speed = 2400;
var $loopLength = 5;
var toc = [], 
  $that = [], 
    $offset = []; // define global arrays

setInterval(function clock() {
  $parents.trigger('tic');
}, $speed);

$.fn.play = function() {
  $(this).on('tic', function() {
    $child.each(function(i) {
      $that[i] = $(this);
      $offset[i] = ($that[i].parent().index() % $loopLength) * $speed / $loopLength;
      toc[i] = setTimeout(function() { // define individual timeouts
        $that[i].toggleClass('special');
      }, $offset[i]);
    });
    return this;
  });
};

$parents.play();

$(document).scroll(function() {
  $parents.off('tic');
  clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
  $.each(toc,function(i){
    clearTimeout(toc[i]); // specify each of the timeouts to clear
  });
  $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
    $parents.play();
    $.each(toc,function(i){
      toc[i] = setTimeout(function() { // resume each of the timeouts
        $that[i].toggleClass('special');
      }, $offset[i]);
  });    
  }, 200));
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  background: red;
  height: 25px;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.child {
  background: pink;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.special {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parents">
  <div class="parent"><div class="child"></div></div>
  <div class="parent"><div class="child"></div></div>
  <div class="parent"><div class="child"></div></div>
  <div class="parent"><div class="child"></div></div>
  <div class="parent"><div class="child"></div></div>
  <div class="parent"><div class="child"></div></div>
  <div class="parent"><div class="child"></div></div>
  <div class="parent"><div class="child"></div></div>
  <div class="parent"><div class="child"></div></div>
  <div class="parent"><div class="child"></div></div>
  <div class="parent"><div class="child"></div></div>
  <div class="parent"><div class="child"></div></div>
  <div class="parent"><div class="child"></div></div>
  <div class="parent"><div class="child"></div></div>
  <div class="parent"><div class="child"></div></div>
  <div class="parent"><div class="child"></div></div>
</div>
```